# Table with dropdown does not resize in IE 7 when dropdown within changes its content

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

My page consists of a table containing two dropdowns. When the first dropdown (group) changes, the second one gets new content (JavaScript), depending on the first selection.

[image: Process Monitor]

In IE7 and IE8 in Compatibility View however the second dropdown will not resize the table.

[image]

This is what I would expect and how it looks like in other browsers (The dropdown extends to the size of its largest value):

[image]

Any idea how I could get the same behavior in IE7?

This is the code:

```
<table border="1" style="background-color: silver; margin: 0; padding: 0">
<tr>
    <td style="background-color: #336; color: white; font-weight: bold">Process Monitor  </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
    <table style="border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <tr>
        <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><form name="rid_select" "action="?" method="GET">
            <select id="pvar_pri" name="pvar_pri" onChange="setOptions(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                <option value="0">Select group</option>
                <option value="5">Item 1</option>
                <option value="10">Item 2</option>
            </select>
            <select id="pvar_sec" name="pvar_sec" onChange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="">Select variable</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Select">
        </form></td>
        <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Just realized, that the behavior is the same in IE7 as in IE8 compatibility view and updated the description accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really have try to solve this issue using only CSS but still have not got any results.

I can offer you an alternative solution as your table is small and redrawing it should not take much time and resources:

1. Add ID of the table that holds the form

   ```
   <table id="FormCointaner">
   ```
2. Set onchange function of the first select box that redraws the table
   on each value changed

   ```
   $(document).on('change','#pvar_pri',function(){
       $('#FormCointaner').html($('#FormCointaner').html());
   });
   ```

According to me, because of some reason, IE is not redrawing the table when new elements are added.

You can check my idea here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jnKnx/